# Android - Where to set the color of pressed,focused... Tabs?

Tags: android, colors, tabs, state

I created a small Tab-Layout.

Now how can i specify the color of the TabWidget depending on its state (focused,pressed..)

I built a new .xml, but i dont know how to set it to my Tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
    android:id="@+id/tabSelector"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:background="#32CD32"/>  <br />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok your selector must be into your res/drawable folder

this is the way to set your selector to the first tab ( getChildAt(0) )

```
tabs = getTabHost();
...
...
...
tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.my_selector);
```

Comment: changed to setBackgroundColor =)